# Use another component in a spec

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am using angular forms and I want to perform tests on my form in component A to check if it is valid.
In another component B - I have a function that opens ngModal that holds component A (the form).
when I write the tests of the form of component A I want to first open the form(the modal) ( that is done by the function that is in component B. Now how do I do that ? Do I need to have a mocked instance of the B component? if so, how do I do that? 
here is my test so far:

```
it('should direction field be valid' ,() => {
  //call the function in component B that opens the form
  //How to mock B ???
   B.openModalForm()
   A.direction.setValue("12")
   expect(A.myForm.valid).toBeTruthy)
}
```

Comment: the spec file of your A component  will always have access to the form defined inside it, component A's spec file is only meant to test the functionality that is defined in it. If B is the parent of A then, inside B's spec you can access A using fixture.componentInstance but not the other way round

Comment: how do I trigger the function that is defined outside the tested component?

Comment: I don't see the point of testing component B from component A. You should mock B to keep A isolated and vice versa. Modal services should be injected as a mock service. Otherwise you're just doing an integration test and Protractor is a better tool for that job.